How to capture the onButton click event in google chat app?
I am trying to develop a google chat app where we ask a question to a user.. ("How are you?") and then we have a dropdown with values ("Good","Okay")
and a Submit button.
When I click on submit button. I want to capture what option the user has clicked along with the question.
I see that when clicking the chat app triggers an interaction event but where and how should I capture it?
Can I capture using App script? Please help me.
I tried using this code "
`
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const key = require('./cred.json'); // Replace with secure credential retrieval
const spaceId = "SpaceID"; // Replace with your Google Chat Space ID
const appScriptURL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/ScriptID/exec"; // Replace with your Apps Script Web App URL

// Set up JWT client
const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email,
  null,
  key.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot']
);

// Authorize the client
jwtClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Authorization failed:', err);
    return;
  }

  // Initialize Google Chat API
  const chat = google.chat({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: jwtClient
  });

  // Function to encode form data as query parameters
  function encodeFormData(data) {
    return Object.keys(data)
      .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
      .join('&');
  }

  // Send the specified card message
  const message = {
    parent: 'spaces/' + spaceId,
    requestBody: {
      cardsV2: [
        {
          cardId: 'unique-card-id',
          card: {
            header: {
              title: "A question has been assigned!",
              imageUrl: "https://developers.google.com/chat/images/quickstart-app-avatar.png",
            },
            sections: [
              {
                collapsible: false,
                uncollapsibleWidgetsCount: 1,
                widgets: [
                  {
                    decoratedText: {
                      text: "How are you feeling today?"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    selectionInput: {
                      name: "Answer",
                      label: "Answer",
                      type: "DROPDOWN",
                      items: [
                        {
                          text: "Good",
                          value: "good"
                        },
                        {
                          text: "Normal",
                          value: "normal"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    buttonList: {
                      buttons: [
                        {
                          text: "Submit",
                          onClick: {
                            
                             
                              openLink: {
                                url: appScriptURL + "?" + encodeFormData({
                                  formData: JSON.stringify({
                                    question: "How are you feeling today?",
                                    // Add more data as needed
                                  })
                                })
                              }
                         
                          },
                          disabled: false
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  chat.spaces.messages.create(message, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error sending message:', err);
      return
    }
    console.log('Message sent:', res.data);
  });
});`

I don't know how to capture an event and send some where.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
